# Include view in custom block with arguments

Tags: include, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've build a view with some contextual filters. I would like to include the view in a custom PHP block and provide them with the arguments. I've been searching for a couple of hours now and stil I haven't found a solid solution. I've tried `view_embed_view`, `view_include_view`, `view_load()`, `module_invoke`,... And many more.

Either I'm doing something wrong, or I still haven't found the right way to do something like this.

Anyone with tips or advice?

Answer (score 0):

First things first (I thought I better check), do you have a good reason to be embedding a view into a block? Could you give some more information on you're use case as there may be a better way of doing it.

As far as I'm aware to simply embed a view you should use `views_embed_view()`. [This function](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) takes the view name, display ID and any additional arguments are passed to views as 'views arguments'.

If you're still having trouble it might be an idea to post your code.